# Manually partition sum of squares for fixed effects model

Tags: regression, anova, multiple-regression, variance, sums-of-squares

I am trying to manually partition the sum of squares of a simple fixed effects linear model. However, I simply cannot get my partitioned sum-of-squares to add up to my total sum-of-squares. What am I doing wrong?

````r
# One realization of `rnorm(10, 0, 1)`
noise <- c(-0.48698389, -0.89996146, 0.32048085, 0.31472992,
           -1.04079374, 0.38544421, 0.79755477, -0.55370181,
           0.17731321, 0.04298504)

B <- rep(0:1, each = 5)
E <- rep(0:1, 5)
Y <- 5 * B + 2 * E + noise
fit <- lm(Y ~ B + E)

n <- length(Y)
y <- Y - mean(Y)
y2 <- y ^ 2
tot.SS <- sum(y2)

YB <- B * fit$coefficients["B"]
yb <- YB - mean(YB)
yb2 <- yb ^ 2
B.effect <- sum(yb2)

YE <- E * fit$coefficients["E"]
ye <- YE - mean(YE)
ye2 <- ye ^ 2
E.effect <- sum(ye2)

Ypred <- YB + YE
YR <- Y - Ypred
yr2 <- YR ^ 2
resid.effect <- sum(yr2)

all.effect <- resid.effect + B.effect + E.effect
print(paste("Computed effects: ", all.effect))
# [1] "Computed effects:  88.9037194169925"
print(paste("Total sum of squares: ", tot.SS))
# [1] "Total sum of squares:  98.1221885328716"
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with the code in the question. The first one is that the residuals effect (`resid.effect`) is not correctly computed, because the value for the Intercept, which is fitted by the `lm` model, is not taken into account. This is the correct way of computing `Ypred`:

```r
Ypred <- fit$coefficients["(Intercept)"] + YB + YE
```

The second issue is related to the fact that the example given in the question does not have a balanced design. Indeed, there are 2 cases of E=1 and 3 cases of E=0 when B=0, and 2 cases of E=0 and 3 cases of E=1 when B=1. When developing the equations for the sum of squares, a cross product appears, which is `2 * sum (ye * yb)`, and whose value was not taken into account in the code. Here is a minimally modified version of the original code, such that it works (i.e. the two final calls to `print` show identical values):

```r
# One realization of `rnorm(10, 0, 1)`
noise <- c(-0.48698389, -0.89996146, 0.32048085, 0.31472992,
           -1.04079374, 0.38544421, 0.79755477, -0.55370181,
           0.17731321, 0.04298504)

B <- rep(0:1, each = 5)
E <- rep(0:1, 5)
Y <- 5 * B + 2 * E + noise
fit <- lm(Y ~ B + E)

n <- length(Y)
y <- Y - mean(Y)
y2 <- y ^ 2
tot.SS <- sum(y2)

YB <- B * fit$coefficients["B"]
yb <- YB - mean(YB)
yb2 <- yb ^ 2
B.effect <- sum(yb2)

YE <- E * fit$coefficients["E"]
ye <- YE - mean(YE)
ye2 <- ye ^ 2
E.effect <- sum(ye2)

Ypred <- fit$coefficients["(Intercept)"] + YB + YE
YR <- Y - Ypred
yr2 <- YR ^ 2
resid.effect <- sum(yr2)

all.effect <- resid.effect + B.effect + E.effect + 2 * sum(ye * yb)
print(paste("Computed effects: ", all.effect))
# [1] "Computed effects:  98.1221885328716"
print(paste("Total sum of squares: ", tot.SS))
# [1] "Total sum of squares:  98.1221885328716"
```

Below is an example with balanced design that follows the conventions of the original code. Notice that there is no need for adding the term `2 * sum(ye * yb)` to `all.effects` (since its value is equal to zero, anyway):

```r
# One realization of `rnorm(12, 0, 1)`
noise <- c(-0.71181782, -0.12173941, -0.37700219, -0.23534021,
           0.20056269, 0.46490554, 0.97869267, -0.49941705,
           0.03854682, 0.49561333, 1.02325336, -0.23959159)

B <- rep(0:1, each = 6)
E <- rep(0:1, 6)
Y <- 5 * B + 2 * E + noise
fit <- lm(Y ~ B + E)

n <- length(Y)
y <- Y - mean(Y)
y2 <- y ^ 2
tot.SS <- sum(y2)

YB <- B * fit$coefficients["B"]
yb <- YB - mean(YB)
yb2 <- yb ^ 2
B.effect <- sum(yb2)

YE <- E * fit$coefficients["E"]
ye <- YE - mean(YE)
ye2 <- ye ^ 2
E.effect <- sum(ye2)

Ypred <- fit$coefficients["(Intercept)"] + YB + YE
YR <- Y - Ypred
yr2 <- YR ^ 2
resid.effect <- sum(yr2)

all.effect <- resid.effect + B.effect + E.effect
print(paste("Computed effects: ", all.effect))
# [1] "Computed effects:  100.760110733347"
print(paste("Total sum of squares: ", tot.SS))
# [1] "Total sum of squares:  100.760110733347"
```